# DisplayFullScreen vs WindowState

Tags: vba

Are there any fundamental differences between the following two properties:

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
```

and

```
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is; the documentation is helpful:

1. [`Application.DisplayFullScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayfullscreen)

   > "Full-screen mode maximizes the application window so that it fills the entire screen *and hides the application title bar*."
2. [`Application.WindowState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.windowstate)

   > The first example states that `Application.WindowState = xlMaximized` "maximizes the application window in Microsoft Excel."

Comment: DisplayFullScreen doesn't hide the title bar for me.  I had to resort to an API to get that accomplished.  Am I doing anything incorrectly then?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't hide the title bar for you, worked fine for me. Possibly related to the note that "toolbars, the status bar, and the formula bar maintain separate display settings for full-screen mode and normal mode." (?)